Firestore security rules for users to be able to delete their profiles in react native
In the same main users directory, I'm duplicating a user profile (with a new name), before deleting the original user directory. My current working rules do not seem to be secure [BELOW]. Can anyone please tell me what vulnerabilities I might be leaving my react native expo app open to with these Firebase Security Rules  or if some aspects are unnecessary:
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;

    allow create: if request.auth != null 
    && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id;

    allow update: if request.auth != null 
    && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id 
    && request.auth.uid == userId;

    allow delete: if request.auth != null;
}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
***** EDIT:
After Frank van Puffelen's sound advice everything works other than... see: "" [BELOW]. This rule failure is due to my renaming the duplicated file in the same directory. Any advice on a different approach would be appreciated.:
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
      
    // Frank van Puffelen’s sound suggestions [BELOW]
    allow create: if request.auth != null 
    && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id
    && request.auth.uid == userId; //  ***** this fails my duplication *****

    allow update: if request.auth != null 
    && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id 
    && request.auth.uid == resource.data.id
    && request.auth.uid == userId;
      
    allow delete: if request.auth != null
    && request.auth.uid == resource.data.id
    && request.auth.uid == userId;
}

Here's the duplication part of my react native code:
// Get a reference to the original document
const deleteUser = doc(db, `users/${user?.uid}/`);
const deleteUserDoc = await getDoc(deleteUser);
            
if(!deleteUserDoc.exists()) {
    console.error("User document doesn't exist.");
    return;
}
      
const deleteUserData = deleteUserDoc.data();

// Create a new document reference for the duplicated data 
const dupeUser = doc(firestore, 'users', `Dupe:${user?.uid}/`); //  Causes Rules error
        
// Save the duplicated data
await setDoc(dupeUser, deleteUserData);

Any further help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!!

You're missing the request.auth.uid == userId check in the create clause. Is there any specific reason for not wanting to enforce that check there?

@FrankvanPuffelen based on your help, I believe the issue is that I delete the authorization at the end of the entire process which is not possible with the rules you recommend. I'll add your recommended rules after that change and let you know, Thanks!

On your first comment: it works yes, but it allows a user to create a document with any document ID they chose. Rather than following up here, check my answer below for a longer explanation of the changes I recommend - and follow up there if needed.

Security is not a yes/no question, so asking an open-ended "what did I miss here" is hard to answer definitively.
That said, here are a few things that jump out:
Enforcing the userId document ID upon creation
You're missing the request.auth.uid == userId check in the create clause. Unless there's a specific reason for not wanting to enforce that check upon creation, I'd recommend:
allow create: if request.auth != null 
&& request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id
&& request.auth.uid == userId; // 

Don't allow updating the id field in updates
I recommend disallowing updates to the id field, unless you have a requirement to allow transferring ownership of a document (in which case your rules will become a lot more complex).
Based on the simpler case, tht'd be:
allow update: if request.auth != null 
&& request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id 
&& request.auth.uid == resource.data.id  // 
&& request.auth.uid == userId;

Users should only be able to delete their own document
Right now any user can delete any document, which is a big security risk.
My guess it that you'll want each user to only be able to delete their own document, which'd be:
allow delete: if request.auth != null
&& request.auth.uid == resource.data.id  // 
&& request.auth.uid == userId; // 


Everything worked after removal of auth deletion at end of process, other than this "&& request.auth.uid == userId; // " part of "allow create:". Failure due to duplication of directory is a different name than the original {userId} so as to no longer be viewable. Should I record dupe to a new directory? I think that would drastically change my Rules.??

FrankvanPuffelen is there a way to detect if my new duplicated user directory contains(userId) as opposed to == userId ?

Sorry, I'm struggling to understand your first comment here. If you're struggling with a specific operation, please edit your question to show the updated rules (as an edit at the end) and the code for the operation that doesn't work.
